# How do i invert the delete mappings in vim?

Tags: vim

I tend to delete using shift+x more than X. How do i remap x to X and vice versa so that i don’t have to shift X everytime I want to delete a character in vim.

Comment: Mapping is such a basic part of Vim. What did you try? Also, `x` and `X` are not mappings so this wouldn't a remapping.

Answer (score 1):

The following two lines will invert `x` and `X`:

```vim
:nnoremap x X
:nnoremap X x
```

This uses `:help :nnoremap`, it will create a non-recursive mapping in normal mode only.